# CRM plugin registration tool resize issue - Win 10/1366x768

Tags: windows-10, dynamics-crm, screen-resolution, window-resize

I am unable to register a plugin assembly using the plugin registration tool for Dynamics 365. This is due to the Tool Resizing/Screen resolution issue on my laptop. I'm using a Win 10 laptop with 1366x768 resolution. The plugin registration tool buttons are out of the screen boundaries (bottom). I had no luck trying to use the 'Tab' key to control the buttons. 
The registration tool won't reduce in size beyond a certain point. 
Same problem with other versions https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/179132/586325#586325

Any windows hack to make the tool shrink or find an alternative to accomplish my task would be of great help.

thanks 
Rajesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

#### Try going backwards with tab.

After you load your assembly and choose your options, place your cursor in the Step 1 box.  Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, then press <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Use registration tool from XrmToolbox

Use the registration tool that is available in the XrmToolbox.  It's a much older version, before the tool was rebuilt with WPF.  I know it will allow you to at least register a plugin in a 2013/2015/2016 org.

Comment: I confirm that XrmToolbox regtool works everywhere despite looking like the 2011 tool

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Polshgiant 

I tried using XrmToolbox, but the plugin won't register. Using keyboard short cuts worked for me, solved the purpose.